# Edithig Data table after binding to a gridview.

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

I have a vb.net application which is binding data to a gridview. After binding the data I want to add new row to the existing data table. is it possible. If yes can any one suggest me a way..

Comment: This is not a tutorial site where we "suggest" things.  Ypu are expected to do your own research and post a specific question with code illustrating where you are stuck.  See [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms (or WPF?), create the Row, fill it and add it to DataTable:

```
DataRow newrow = myDataTable.NewRow() ;
newrow[0] = ... ;
newRow[1] = ... ;
myDataTable.Rows.Add(newrow) ;
```

As the DataGridView is bound, it will be automatically updated.

*Note: the above code doesn't update the underlying DataTable source (collection, sql database, excel file ...)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnionSelect in your sql query to add rows with misc values.

```
Select column as C1 from table
unionselect 'Misc data' as c1 from table
```